# Find a permutation $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \circ(1 5 6 4 3) = \tau$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

( Question before it was using $\tau$ in $S_{15}$ with form $\tau=(8\ 5\ 2\ 13)(1\ 3\ 10\ 9\ 7\ 15)(4\ 11\ 6\ 12)$ )

I'm stuck on this as I am not sure whether they want me to go through a random number of permutations for $\alpha$ to get to $\tau$ eventually or if there is an actual way to figure it out by working backwards.

If its just by working it out by hand and multiplying perms together, I'm just stuck on figuring out what random permutations to use like for example:

Do I just use whatever numbers are not contained in $(1\ 5\ 6\ 4\ 3)$ i.e. use $(2\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ 14\ 15)$?
I feel like this is probably simple but I'm just stuck, any hints would be great!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun Not too necessary in this case, though. No exponents, fractions or integrals that look ugly in pure text. And $(1\,5\,6\,4\,3)$ is actually somewhat of a hassle to write, compared to non-math-mode.

Comment: Find a permutation $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \beta = \tau$?  Easy.  $\alpha = \tau \beta^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, multiply the equation with the inverse of $(1, 5,6,4,3)$ from the right - the inverse is $(1, 3,4,6,5)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $G$ is a group and $a,b\in G$, then the equation $xa=b$ always have a unique solution for $x\in G$, that is, $x=ba^{-1}$.

In this case, the unique solution for $\alpha$ will be
$$\tau(15643)^{-1}=\tau(13465).$$